# Running an AsyncTask periodically

Tags: android

I want to update a ListView every 30 seconds with new data being loaded from an AsyncTask. I want to get some advice as to the best methods to carry this kind of activity out, or if it would not be advised to update the view in this fashion. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the thing you are going to implement in AsyncTask will complete in 30 seconds exactly?

Comment: It will, as it is only some minor text manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use recursinve `handler.postdelayed` method to call `asynctask`.. But if you want my suggestion I will tell you to implement `CursorLoader` in your caseou

To know more about cursor loader you can check these links ( first 3 google search :p)

https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/525313/Using-Cursor-Loader-in-Android
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Comment: Hmm never worked with cursorLoader before, any links for that?